# Conditional probability of selecting colored cards from two boxes

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question from my statistics class I am struggling with. I suspect that conditional probability is involved but am unsure how to incorporate both assumptions that the first two cards from box 1 are the same color and that both cards from box 2 are black. Would Bayes Rule be helpful?

Box 1 contains 2 white cards and 3 black cards. Box 2 contains 5 white cards and 2 black cards. Two cards are drawn at random, without replacement, from Box 1 and put into Box 2. Next, two cards are drawn at random, without replacement, from Box 2. Suppose the two cards drawn from Box 1 were both the same color, and the two cards drawn from Box 2 were both black. Find the probability that the two cards drawn from Box 1 were both black.

Comment: Thanks, Andre and Marcus! Got the same answer with both set-ups!

Answer (score 2):

We use the *definition* of conditional probability. Let $S$ be the event the cards drawn from Box 1 are of the same colour, **and** the cards drawn from Box 2 are both black.  Let $A$ be the event the cards drawn from Box 1 are both black.  We want $\Pr(A\mid S)$, which is $\Pr(S\cap A)/\Pr(S)$.

So to finish we need to find a couple of probabilities. We will calculate $\Pr(S)$.

The probability that two whites were transferred is $1/\binom{5}{2}$. **Given** that this happened, the probability the cards drawn from Box 2 were both black is $1/\binom{9}{2}$.

The probability that two blacks were transferred is $3/\binom{5}{2}$. **Given** that this happened, the probability the cards drawn from Box 2 were both black is $\binom{4}{2}/\binom{9}{2}$.

It follows that
$$\Pr(S)=\frac{1}{\binom{5}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{9}{2}}+ \frac{3}{\binom{5}{2}}\cdot \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}.$$

The probability $\Pr(S\cap A)$ is a little easier to find. In essence we have already computed it.